# How can I bring my family if I am an exchange student in Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, family

As a PhD student, I am going from Poland to Germany for six months as a research scholar. Then I will have to either get back to Poland or go on another trip to a French university.

I want to bring my spouse and a minor child to Europe from Bangladesh. Bangladesh doesn't have a Polish embassy. Visa seekers have to make trips to New Delhi, India, which is not possible for my spouse to make.

German immigration rules say that in order to bring my family, I need to have at least one year of a temporary residence permit in Germany.

What would be the most convenient way to bring my family to Europe?

1. How about a language learning visa for my wife?
2. How about I go for an Erasmus+ program and stay in Germany for two semesters including the summer vacation in the middle?

Comment: If those are the rules, you can’t ‘get around’ them.

Comment: If you do not fulfill the conditions, they will simply not give you a visa to you or your family, there is no workaround.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, How about Language Learning Visa?

Comment: @user366312 What are you trying to get around? The trip to New Delhi to apply for a visa, or the length of temporary residence rule? The language visa appears to be an option, if your family can find a suitable language course in Germany, prove funds, and meet the other eligibility requirements eg https://www.nomadenberlin.com/german-language-course-visa But presumably the application would still require them to make the trip to New Delhi. And you’d need to be sure the visa decision time chimes with your own length of stay in Germany

Comment: @Traveller, *But presumably the application would still require them to make the trip to New Delhi.* --- This is not true. There is a German embassy in Dhaka, Bangladesh

Comment: @user366312 You need to do some more research. As it stands your situation has too many variables making your question impossible to answer.